# Pass some values from one job to another

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I have three jobs which will be built inside a pipeline job as below

```
build 'job1'
build 'job2'
build 'job3'
```

**job2** can take 2 parameters. Which should be coming from **job1**. 
Let **job1** is creating a folder in some particular location (eg; C:\tests). I need to pass the name of the folder which is created **job1** to **job2**. How can I do that ?

I need the same parameters to be passed to **job3** also.

What can I do in job1 and in the pipeline to send and receive these parameters ?

I don't want to edit the **job1** to have post build  options to build **job2** with parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From job1:

```
env.SOMETHING = someValue
```

Define the parameters in job2. In the master job,

```
def b1 = build 'job1'
def something = b1.buildVariables.SOMETHING
build job: 'job2', parameters: …
```

Comment: If I do stage "Package"; def packageJob = build job: 'Package'; stage 'Live'; build job: 'Live', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'LIVE_VERSION', value: value: packageJob.buildVariables.VERSION]]] then it fails as null was passed - VERSION in Package job is populated using environmentVariables plugin and it exists on "Environment Variables" HTML page for job. How can I access VERSION in pipeline script?

Comment: I've found that packageJob.rawBuild.environment.VERSION is working but it requires whitelisting two above getters. It looks that buildVariables contains only my build parameter - will it include more variables including injected by environmentVariables plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Pipeline, I would define the directory name in the Pipeline, and pass that into all three `build` steps as a parameter.

Comment: I don't know the directory name till I run the **job1** . So How can I pass it via pipeline parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know the directory name till i run the job1

and since you do not want any post build actions.

Could you:

1. Run job1 and store the resulting directory in a text file
2. In job2 and job3 read the directory you need from that file.